# Can you freeze an unbaked sour cream apple pie?

Tags: freezing

I am concerned the sour cream will separate during freezing.  Did not know if I added corn starch if that would help.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Recipes that contain sour cream (and other dairy products) can be frozen, but they need to be cooked first. You can cook the filling, add it to a a parchment lined pie pan, and then pop in the freezer. Once frozen you can remove from pie shell and place in a freezer bag for a frozen pie shaped disc to add to your pie shell at your leisure.